# Why doesn't my pic get smaller in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body {
      background-color:olive;
      margin:0;
    }

    nav {
      background-color:aqua;
      position:sticky;
      top:0;
      border:1px solid red;

    }
    
    #container{
      max-height:1800px;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;

      
    }

     a {
      
      background-color:chocolate;
      padding:7px;
      border-radius:10px; 
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    #container > a:hover{
      opacity:0.5;
    }

    #logout {
     margin-left:auto;
    }

    .bonus {
       margin-left:10px;
     }
    /* nav is finally done after 1.5 hours lol and another 30mins  */

   

   

    hr {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #gallery {
      display:flex;
      justify-content:flex-start;
      flex-direction:row;
      width:60px;
      height:800px;

    }

    .class {
      flex:1;
      width:20%;
    }

    .image {
      align-self:center;
    }
```

```html
`<body>

  <img src=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531870972494-627796a756dc?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=72a43beae93d56392f98f6eda2cdd8cb&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 width="100%" height="150" "border-radius:40px">
<nav>
  <div id="main-content">
  <div id="container" >
    <a id="main" href="index.html">Main</a>  
    <a id="information" class="bonus" href="information.html" >Statistics</a>
    <a id="contacts" class="bonus" href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
    <a id="media" class="bonus" href="media.html" style="background-color:#bad455">Media</a>
    <a id="logout" href="logout.html">Log out</a>
    
</div>
  </div>

  
</nav>


<main>


  <div id="gallery">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/128756/pexels-photo-128756.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="images/one.jpg"></div>

  </div>


</main>
  

  
</body>
```

Currently I'm trying to make this picture to take 33% in flexbox so I could fit 3 pictures in one row. But for some reason it doesn't work that way. Could someone explain me why? I'm trying a different picture than in this snippet. Here's what's happening to my website currently when I try to apply the code that is in the snippet:

http://prntscr.com/k9is4z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your reference, I love this flexbox overview: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

First of all - not quite sure what this is supposed to do:

```
.class {
  flex:1;
  width:20%;
}
```

Do you have a classname of 'class' somewhere that I'm not seeing?

My understanding is you want to have rows of images, each with 3 images that are 1/3 of the width of the view.

A couple of things are needed it looks like.

First, add the 'flex-wrap' option to your gallery element. You can actually combine the 'flex-direction' and 'flex-wrap' options into a shorthand method 'flex-flow' and specify 'row wrap' in this case.

Second, I would remove the width and height from #gallery. Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't your gallery element expand to 100% of the view so that your images each take up 1/3 of the width of the view?

Also, I would tend to avoid specifying fixed px width and height, especially when using flexbox. One of the huge benefits of flexbox is that it should make responsive layouts super easy! So better to think in terms of %.

Based on these first steps #gallery would look like this:

```
#gallery {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Third, your child div elements should be set to width of 33% so they will automatically size to 1/3 of the width of the parent (the #gallery).

```
#gallery > div {
  width: 33%
}
```

Fourth, the width for your image elements should be 100% of their container (the div elements).

```
img {
  width: 100%
}
```

This should do the trick. There are some more options available with image sizing/manipulation but I didn't really see any mention of that. Let me know if you need some more help!